# deploying axis 2 in tomcat

Tags: web-services, tomcat, apache-axis

I have a Web Service deployed (as an aar) file to `Axis2`, But I am not able to deploy `axis 2` in tomcat eventually not able to check if the `webservices` are working. I copied the `axis 2` folder along with all the aar files in tomcat directory. But I don't understand where should I make the configuration changes (like setting AXIS2 path). When I checked list of services with this url : (ip address of the application):`8080/axis2/services/listServices`, I got the network error (that means axis 2 itself is not deployed in tomcat).It is not a standalone application. It is an already developed project. Please help.
Thanks,

Comment: What kind of IDE you used?

Comment: I am not using any IDE for this. The application is deployed on some other server. We have access to its source files through winscp. So I had copied axis 2 folder along with .aar files for webservice in tomcat/webapps directory.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below blog on how to deploy axis2 in tomcat and write/test  sample services.

http://jayalalk.blogspot.com/2014/01/writing-axis2-services-and-deploying-in.html

Answer (score 0):

@jayalalk answer works fine if you need to create new web application itself and may be just standalone SOAP web-services project.

But if you have already project with say name `abc` and you want to add SOAP web-services to same, then following approach will work.

1. Copy all content(100% is not required, but its better you do it to start with) of the Axis2.war to abc except web.xml.
2. Merge, `axis2.war/WEB-INF/web.xml` content with `abc/WEB-INF/web.xml`, by copying following to respectively inside `<web-app>` XML tag.

   ```
   <servlet>
   <display-name>Apache-Axis Servlet</display-name>
   <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet>
   <display-name>Apache-Axis AxisAdmin Servlet (Web Admin)</display-name>
   <servlet-name>AxisAdminServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/servlet/AxisServlet</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

   <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.jws</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

   <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

   <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>AxisAdminServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/axis2-admin/*</url-pattern>
   ```

I have answered similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51604408/deploy-axis-2-in-tomcat-and-access-your-web-service-in-a-custom-path/51655549#51655549), hope it help others.