# Deploy Axis 2 in Tomcat and access your web service in a custom path

Tags: web-services, soap, apache-axis

I have an Axis2 based web service which I deployed in Tomcat.First I downloaded axis2.war & placed it in Tomcat's webapps folder.It created axis2 folder & its sub-folders.In the WEB-INF sub-folder of Axis2, in the `services` sub-folder I place my .aar file.Then in my browser I go to http://localhost:8080/axis2. It has a link services, which lists out all the services.Suppose my service is HelloWorldService. So the path where it is accessible is

> http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/HelloWorldService

But I do not want to reveal to world that my web service is driven by Axis2. Suppose I want the path to be

> http://localhost:8080/abc/services/HelloWorldService

How to do that? Do I have to rename `axis2` folder to `abc`. I also have an web application `abc` deployed in the same Tomcat. Do I copy content of `axis2` sub-folder to `abc`. I tried that, did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I also have an web application `abc` deployed in the same Tomcat. Do I copy content of axis2 sub-folder to abc.

You're thinking in right direction and yes, you have to copy all content(100% is not required, but its better you do it to start with) of the `Axis2.war` to `abc` except `web.xml`.

You have to merge, `axis2.war/WEB-INF/web.xml` content with `abc/WEB-INF/web.xml`, by copying following to respectively inside `<web-app>` XML tag.

```
    <servlet>
        <display-name>Apache-Axis Servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet</servlet-class>
        <!--<init-param>-->
        <!--<param-name>axis2.xml.path</param-name>-->
        <!--<param-value>/WEB-INF/conf/axis2.xml</param-value>-->
        <!--<param-name>axis2.xml.url</param-name>-->
        <!--<param-value>http://localhost/myrepo/axis2.xml</param-value>-->
        <!--<param-name>axis2.repository.path</param-name>-->
        <!--<param-value>/WEB-INF</param-value>-->
        <!--<param-name>axis2.repository.url</param-name>-->
        <!--<param-value>http://localhost/myrepo</param-value>-->
        <!--</init-param>-->
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <display-name>Apache-Axis AxisAdmin Servlet (Web Admin)</display-name>
        <servlet-name>AxisAdminServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>



<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet/AxisServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jws</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AxisAdminServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/axis2-admin/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Hope it works for you! If it doen't work update your question and I could refocus the answer.

Comment: I  discovered that my line of thinking was correct, problem was elsewhere - in the initialization part of the web application which is unrelated to Axis. For the Axis part, used axis2-aar-maven-plugin for creating required structure (services folder under WEB-INF & placing the aar file there).